# POWERAPPS SQL data source Column does not appear

Tags: sql, forms, field, powerapps

Have a power-apps application that uses sql server as a data source
I added a  column to a table  so that it would show up in an existing form . However
for some reason when I click on 'add fields'- (to add a new card),  the new column is not there ???. I have refreshed the connection, deleted it and reconnected  it  but it doesn't appear.  Strangely, if I create a new form and link to the data source, the  missing column appears ...? is there some tweak that must  be made  on an existing form to so that it gets the new column?  Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have a form, that basically just generates a view on your data. In order to use the new column in your form:

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Basically you have to tell your form manually that there is a new column and you MUST use that. Yes, forms are quiet unintelligent. :)

EDIT: When clicking the ellipses, the column should show up there.